# Кнопка "Игнорировать метку" вылезает за границы всплывающего блока

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, дизайн

> [image: ку]

Comment: На [MSE создал вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344967/260198).

Comment: у них там короче текст :)

Comment: Да и на других локализованных сайтах тоже. Проблема только у нас)

Comment: Обмажутся своими новомодными флексбоксами, а вёрстка как разъезжалась двадцать лет назад с флоатами, так и сегодня разъезжается :(

Comment: @andreymal *как 20 лет назад с таблицами

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кто-то уже подправил перевод для кнопки "Игнорировать метку". Сейчас там просто "Игнорировать":

> [image: Игнорировать]

В таком виде она почти помещается в границы блока. Я взял на себя смелость так же сократить перевод и для кнопки отслеживания метки. Оставил как "Отслеживать". [Перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/4008) появится на сайте после подхватывания.

Должно будет решить проблему дизайна без необходимости ждать фикса от разработчиков: ["Ignore tag" button is out of the borders on the Stack Overflow на Русском](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344967/)

Comment: Получается что Вы решили проблему

Comment: @StrangerintheQ зависит от того, как на неё посмотреть.

Comment: Да, сейчас всё правильно. При наведении на метку, появляется её описание с кнопками в том же контексте.